# css transition issue with slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

i have provided all my codes here all seems good the problem is when i change from last slide to first or the opposite in both case all slides flips differently instead rotating like with other sildes

**`render()`** function is the place where all co-ordinates are calculating
i think the issue is with CSS transition since its the main thing which is animating slides, i dont see any easy fix for this if you can find any tell me please looking for easy solution or possibility without messing too much with co-ordinates . thanks in advance

```js
class slider {
    constructor(){
        if(typeof arguments[0] != "undefined"){
            this.init()
            arguments[0].appendChild(this.html)
            this.calculate()
            this.render(1)
        }
        else{this.init()}
    }
    init(){
        let obj = this
        this.html = `
<div class="root border-2 p-5 border-black m-auto">
    <div class="each border border-black absolute text-center">item name 1</div>
</div>
        ` 
        let el = document.createElement("div")
        el.innerHTML = this.html
        this.html = el.querySelector("*")
        this.root = this.html

        let eEl = this.root.querySelector(".each")
        this.eachTemp = eEl.cloneNode(true)
        eEl.remove()

        this.fillBoxes(6)
        this.html.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            obj.onclick(obj,e)
        })
    }

    onclick(obj,e){
        let t = e.target
        if(t.closest(".each")){
            obj.render(t.index)
        }
    }

    fillBoxes(num){
        for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
            let newEl = this.eachTemp.cloneNode(true)
            newEl.index = i+1
            newEl.innerText = "Item " + (i+1)
            this.html.appendChild(newEl)
        }
        this.els = this.html.querySelectorAll(".each")
    }

    calculate(){
        this.eCor = this.els[0].getClientRects()[0]
        this.mag = this.eCor.width
        this.per = Math.PI / (this.els.length / 2)
        this.deg = this.rtod(this.per)        
    }

    render(index){
        this.els.forEach((each,i)=>{
            let rad = (this.per * i) - this.per*(index-1),
                x = Math.sin(rad)*this.mag,
                y = Math.cos(rad)*this.mag
            if(i+1 == index){each.classList.add("active")}
            else{each.classList.remove("active")}
            each.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px,0%,${y}px)`
            each.style.transform += `rotateY(${this.rtod(rad)}deg)`
        })
    }

    rtod(radians){
        return radians * (180/Math.PI)
    }        

}

const s = new slider(document.body)
```

```css
.each{
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        background: skyblue;
        opacity: 0.8;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        user-select: none;
        filter: brightness(80%);
        transition: all 1s  cubic-bezier(0, 1.22, 0.53, 1.02);
        /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px black; */
    }
    .each:nth-child(odd){background:lightsalmon}
    .root{
        height: 280px;
        width: 280px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 10%;        
        perspective: 1000px;        
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        /* animation: loop 4s infinite linear; */
    }
    .each:hover{
        z-index: 1000 !important;
        filter:brightness(110%);
    }
    .active{
        opacity: 1 !important;
        filter:brightness(100%) !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch between 1 and 6 slides, your calculated `rotatedY` value changes from 0deg to 300deg (or from 300deg to 0deg). But actually you need only ±60deg update. So you need a mechanism to increase/decrease your rotatedY endlessly in both ways, for example 240 -> 300 -> 360 -> 420 -> 480 ... (not 240 -> 300 -> 0 -> 60 -> ...)

I suggest you to have these properties in your class:

```
currentIndex = 1;
radOffset = 0;
```

Then, when you click on element, you need to calculate radOffset (it increases/decreases endlessly):

```
const totalElements = this.els.length;
const rightDiff = t.index > this.currentIndex ? t.index - this.currentIndex : totalElements + t.index - this.currentIndex;
const leftDiff = totalElements - rightDiff;
const closestDiff = rightDiff < leftDiff ? - rightDiff : leftDiff;

this.currentIndex = t.index;
this.radOffset += this.per * closestDiff;
```

Then use it in your render function:

```
let rad = (this.per * i) + this.radOffset,
```

```js
class slider {
    
    currentIndex = 1;
    radOffset = 0;

    rotateOffset = 0;
        constructor(){
            if(typeof arguments[0] != "undefined"){
                this.init()
                arguments[0].appendChild(this.html)
                this.calculate()
                this.render(1)
            }
            else{this.init()}
        }
        init(){
            let obj = this
            this.html = `
    <div class="root border-2 p-5 border-black m-auto">
        <div class="each border border-black absolute text-center">item name 1</div>
    </div>
            ` 
            let el = document.createElement("div")
            el.innerHTML = this.html
            this.html = el.querySelector("*")
            this.root = this.html
    
            let eEl = this.root.querySelector(".each")
            this.eachTemp = eEl.cloneNode(true)
            eEl.remove()
    
            this.fillBoxes(6)
            this.html.addEventListener("click",function(e){
                obj.onclick(obj,e)
            })
        }
    
        onclick(obj,e){
            let t = e.target
            if(t.closest(".each")){
            
                const totalElements = this.els.length;
                const rightDiff = t.index > this.currentIndex ? t.index - this.currentIndex : totalElements + t.index - this.currentIndex;
                const leftDiff = totalElements - rightDiff;
                const closestDiff = rightDiff < leftDiff ? - rightDiff : leftDiff;

                this.currentIndex = t.index;
                this.radOffset += this.per * closestDiff;
                
                obj.render(t.index);
                
            }
        }
    
        fillBoxes(num){
            for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
                let newEl = this.eachTemp.cloneNode(true)
                newEl.index = i+1
                newEl.innerText = "Item " + (i+1)
                this.html.appendChild(newEl)
            }
            this.els = this.html.querySelectorAll(".each")
        }
    
        calculate(){
            this.eCor = this.els[0].getClientRects()[0]
            this.mag = this.eCor.width
            this.per = Math.PI / (this.els.length / 2)
            this.deg = this.rtod(this.per)        
        }
    
        render(index, rotateDiff){
            this.els.forEach((each,i)=>{
                let rad = (this.per * i) + this.radOffset,
                    x = Math.sin(rad)*this.mag,
                    y = Math.cos(rad)*this.mag
                if(i+1 == index){each.classList.add("active")}
                else{each.classList.remove("active")}
                 
                each.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px,0%,${y}px)`
                each.style.transform += `rotateY(${this.rtod(rad)}deg)`
            })
        }
    
        rtod(radians){
            return Math.round(radians * (180/Math.PI));
        }        
    
    }
    
    const s = new slider(document.body)
```

```css
.each{
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        background: skyblue;
        opacity: 0.8;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        user-select: none;
        filter: brightness(80%);
        transition: all 1s  cubic-bezier(0, 1.22, 0.53, 1.02);
        /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px black; */
    }
    .each:nth-child(odd){background:lightsalmon}
    .root{
        height: 280px;
        width: 280px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 10%;        
        perspective: 1000px;        
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        /* animation: loop 4s infinite linear; */
    }
    .each:hover{
        z-index: 1000 !important;
        filter:brightness(110%);
    }
    .active{
        opacity: 1 !important;
        filter:brightness(100%) !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: wow you really solved this i was really messed up and stuck at the same time it is because i am learning math functions dont know much about it, your solution is really appreciable i thank you for your time and knowledge